# Search module is not working with all content types

Tags: search

In my drupal, i have a search module. This module is not working with all content. For example i have a view. This view's show us announcement. 
When i was trying to search this content type, there is no result.

I'd tried reindex (/admin/config/search/settings)

So can someone give me an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Default behavior of search module is, it search all the content type contents. If you tried to search with content type name then it is not working, because it is not the search module functionality.